# Configuration of Android Email via File

Tags: android, xml, email, configuration

Is there a method for configuration of Android Email client via an XML File?

Example is the functionality in the Apple ecosystem, http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html for enterprise setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. Non-programming Android questions belong elsewhere, such as http://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration is done by the user who is responsible for setting up a Google account on an Android device. From there the email / GMail app automatically synchronizes with Google Mail and maintains its own data and private settings.

But I guess you are asking for the automatic setup of company email accounts on each company phone. To my knowledge there is no solution out there for programatically setting up accounts.

You could however create your own email client app or modify the Open Source client K-9 for making that possible.